# Error after HDF5 file type transfer via socket: OSError: Unable to open file

Tags: python, hdf5, python-sockets, hdf

I recently wrote a client / server application for transferring files in the hickle (HDF5 based file) format. The export, import and reading with the generated file works as intended.

The source code of the client, who sends the file, looks like this:

```
import socket
import hickle

# Creating a socket with IPv4 and TCP
node_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Define Target
node_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1961))

# Send process
with open("my_file.hkl", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = f.read(4096)
        if not bytes_read:
            break

    node_socket.sendall(bytes_read)
```

The server's source code that receives the file looks like this:

```
import socket
import hickle

# Creating a socket with IPv4 and TCP
node_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind port and set it to listen state
node_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1961))
node_socket.listen(1)

# Accept incoming connection
client_socket, addr = node_socket.accept()

# Receive and write to file operation
with open("temp.hkl", "wb") as f:
    while True:
        recieved_pyload = client_socket.recv(4096)
        if not recieved_pyload:
            break

        f.write(recieved_pyload)
```

Now, if I want to load the hickle (HDF5 based) file, with the line

```
data = hickle.load("temp.hkl")
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\network_connector_server.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = hickle.load("temp.hkl")
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\hickle\hickle.py", line 321, in load
    h5f, path, close_flag = file_opener(file_obj, path, 'r', filename)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\hickle\fileio.py", line 147, in file_opener
    return h5.File(f, mode.replace('b','')),path,True
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 567, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr=swmr)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 231, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 106, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Do I need to convert the file first into a HDF5 file or something similar? Thank you in advance!